# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ida/IDAAboutBox

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

How can I resolve this issue??!  Everything seems to be fine with the code but getting this strange exception!  It seems that Netbeans can't find the classes withing my project package!  However I can see that they're all physically there and can be opened by a third party editor.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ida/IDAAboutBox
```

Thanks